# How to transform a simple array of file paths into a nested array representing a file hierarchy in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, traversal, tree-traversal

I need to write a function in PHP that takes the following input array:

```
$inputArray = [
[
    "path" => "/C",
    "basename" => "C",
    "size" => 4096,
    "modified" => 1540579748,
    "type" => "dir",
    "contents" => []
],
[
    "path" => "/C/Recycle.Bin",
    "basename" => "Recycle.Bin",
    "size" => 0,
    "modified" => 1539012172,
    "type" => "dir",
    "contents" => []
],
[
    "path" => "/C/Pictures",
    "basename" => "Pictures",
    "size" => 3164422144,
    "modified" => 1540581569,
    "type" => "file",
    "contents" => []
],
[
    "path" => "/C/Videos",
    "basename" => "Videos",
    "size" => 970752,
    "modified" => 1540579792,
    "type" => "file",
    "contents" => []
],
[
    "path" => "/C/Documents and Settings",
    "basename" => "Documents and Settings",
    "size" => 4096,
    "modified" => 1539022708,
    "type" => "link",
    "contents" => []
],
[
    "path" => "/C/Documents and Settings/Public",
    "basename" => "Public",
    "size" => 4096,
    "modified" => 1539012079,
    "type" => "dir",
    "contents" => []
],
[
    "path" => "/C/Documents and Settings/desktop.ini",
    "basename" => "desktop.ini",
    "size" => 174,
    "modified" => 1506692592,
    "type" => "file",
    "contents" => []
],
[
    "path" => "/C/PerfLogs",
    "basename" => "PerfLogs",
    "size" => 0,
    "modified" => 1506692704,
    "type" => "dir",
    "contents" => []
],
[
    "path" => "/C/Program Files",
    "basename" => "Program Files",
    "size" => 4096,
    "modified" => 1540579745,
    "type" => "dir",
    "contents" => []
],
[
    "path" => "/C/Program Files (x86)",
    "basename" => "Program Files (x86)",
    "size" => 4096,
    "modified" => 1506692707,
    "type" => "dir",
    "contents" => []
],
[
    "path" => "/C/ProgramData",
    "basename" => "ProgramData",
    "size" => 4096,
    "modified" => 1539012665,
    "type" => "dir",
    "contents" => []
],
[
    "path" => "/C/Recovery",
    "basename" => "Recovery",
    "size" => 0,
    "modified" => 1539022717,
    "type" => "dir",
    "contents" => []
],
[
    "path" => "/C/System Volume Information",
    "basename" => "System Volume Information",
    "size" => 4096,
    "modified" => 1539012967,
    "type" => "dir",
    "contents" => []
],
[
    "path" => "/C/Users",
    "basename" => "Users",
    "size" => 4096,
    "modified" => 1539012384,
    "type" => "dir",
    "contents" => []
],
[
    "path" => "/C/Windows",
    "basename" => "Windows",
    "size" => 24576,
    "modified" => 1539011957,
    "type" => "dir",
    "contents" => []
],
[
    "path" => "/C/pagefile.sys",
    "basename" => "pagefile.sys",
    "size" => 1207959552,
    "modified" => 1540581479,
    "type" => "file",
    "contents" => []
],
[
    "path" => "/C/swapfile.sys",
    "basename" => "swapfile.sys",
    "size" => 268435456,
    "modified" => 1540581479,
    "type" => "file",
    "contents" => []
]
];
```

and produces the following output array:

```
$outputArray = [
[
    "path" => "/C",
    "basename" => "C",
    "size" => 4096,
    "modified" => 1540579748,
    "type" => "dir",
    "contents" => [
        [
            "path" => "/C/Recycle.Bin",
            "basename" => "Recycle.Bin",
            "size" => 0,
            "modified" => 1539012172,
            "type" => "dir",
            "contents" => []
        ],
        [
            "path" => "/C/Pictures",
            "basename" => "Pictures",
            "size" => 3164422144,
            "modified" => 1540581569,
            "type" => "file",
            "contents" => []
        ],
        [
            "path" => "/C/Videos",
            "basename" => "Videos",
            "size" => 970752,
            "modified" => 1540579792,
            "type" => "file",
            "contents" => []
        ],
        [
            "path" => "/C/Documents and Settings",
            "basename" => "Documents and Settings",
            "size" => 4096,
            "modified" => 1539022708,
            "type" => "link",
            "contents" => [
                [
                    "path" => "/C/Documents and Settings/Public",
                    "basename" => "Public",
                    "size" => 4096,
                    "modified" => 1539012079,
                    "type" => "dir",
                    "contents" => []
                ],
                [
                    "path" => "/C/Documents and Settings/desktop.ini",
                    "basename" => "desktop.ini",
                    "size" => 174,
                    "modified" => 1506692592,
                    "type" => "file",
                    "contents" => []
                ]
            ]
        ],
        [
            "path" => "/C/PerfLogs",
            "basename" => "PerfLogs",
            "size" => 0,
            "modified" => 1506692704,
            "type" => "dir",
            "contents" => []
        ],
        [
            "path" => "/C/Program Files",
            "basename" => "Program Files",
            "size" => 4096,
            "modified" => 1540579745,
            "type" => "dir",
            "contents" => []
        ],
        [
            "path" => "/C/Program Files (x86)",
            "basename" => "Program Files (x86)",
            "size" => 4096,
            "modified" => 1506692707,
            "type" => "dir",
            "contents" => []
        ],
        [
            "path" => "/C/ProgramData",
            "basename" => "ProgramData",
            "size" => 4096,
            "modified" => 1539012665,
            "type" => "dir",
            "contents" => []
        ],
        [
            "path" => "/C/Recovery",
            "basename" => "Recovery",
            "size" => 0,
            "modified" => 1539022717,
            "type" => "dir",
            "contents" => []
        ],
        [
            "path" => "/C/System Volume Information",
            "basename" => "System Volume Information",
            "size" => 4096,
            "modified" => 1539012967,
            "type" => "dir",
            "contents" => []
        ],
        [
            "path" => "/C/Users",
            "basename" => "Users",
            "size" => 4096,
            "modified" => 1539012384,
            "type" => "dir",
            "contents" => []
        ],
        [
            "path" => "/C/Windows",
            "basename" => "Windows",
            "size" => 24576,
            "modified" => 1539011957,
            "type" => "dir",
            "contents" => []
        ],
        [
            "path" => "/C/pagefile.sys",
            "basename" => "pagefile.sys",
            "size" => 1207959552,
            "modified" => 1540581479,
            "type" => "file",
            "contents" => []
        ],
        [
            "path" => "/C/swapfile.sys",
            "basename" => "swapfile.sys",
            "size" => 268435456,
            "modified" => 1540581479,
            "type" => "file",
            "contents" => []
        ]
    ]
]
];
```

I understand that this can be done with recursion, but I'm having a hard time with it. If somebody could point me in the right direction or provide a working solution, that would be really cool.

Comment: This might be hard to do if you don't want a limit on the amount of layers deep the array can go

Comment: Post your code. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ideally the function would work without any limits on the number of layers deep. Isn’t that what recursion is for (assuming we don’t run out of memory)? Worst case scenario, we can set a max depth of 3 or 4. Anything is better than nothing!

Comment: @user3067352 Yes that is what recursion is for... However, for every layer you will need _another_ layer of recursion

Comment: What will this new array format bring you?

Comment: @Progrock This new array format makes it a little easier for me to build the UI for a file browser. That's all. Thanks again for your edit on pid's answer!

Comment: @user3067352 no problem, do add some example effort code next time, even if it is complete failure!  Otherwise your question will likely be voted down/closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the array by `path` if it's not already ordered:

```
usort($inputArray, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['path'] <=> $b['path'];
});
```

Then nest the items recursively by `path`:

```
function nest(&$directory)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($directory); $i++)
    {
        while ($i + 1 < count($directory) && strpos($directory[$i + 1]['path'], $directory[$i]['path'] . '/') === 0)
        {
            $directory[$i]['contents'][] = $directory[$i + 1];
            array_splice($directory, $i + 1, 1);
        }

        nest($directory[$i]['contents']);
    }
}
```

On case-insensitive filesystems (such as Windows) you may want to replace `strpos()` with `stripos()`, but I didn't test for this so I leave it to you to decide.

Comment: Thank you Progrock for your contribution! :)

Comment: Thank you for your solution and @Progrock for your code cleanup. I have tested this and it does indeed work. This is just what I was looking for! You guys rock!

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to use an array of objects instead, You can take advantage of the way objects are passed like references to simplify creating this kind of structure.

```
sort($inputArray);

foreach ($inputArray as $item) {
    $item = (object) $item;
    $files[$item->path] = $item;
    $files[substr($item->path, 0, strrpos($item->path, '/'))]->contents[] = $item;
}

$result = reset($files);
```

If objects won't work for you, JSON encode/decode can convert the objects in the result to arrays.

```
$result = json_decode(json_encode($result), true);
```

Comment: you can add `$result = json_decode(json_encode($result), true);` to the end

Comment: @user1597430, good point, that would turn it all back to arrays